# How do I get the current page language from Hubspot with hubl

Tags: hubspot

I'm using a language switcher for my Hubspot Page that switches the languages of pages by changing url ( like ...xyz.com/en-gb/ )
Is there any hubl supported variable or function to get the language and country information dynamically by using hubl? I want to display content depending on current page-language.

For now, I will use {{ request.path }} and parse the language by myself.

Thanks
Marileen

Answer (score 2):

You can use this helper to display the current language tag:

```
{{ content.language.languageTag }}
```

Or using it with some logic, for example:

```
{% if content.language.languageTag == "en" %}
```

Btw I searched for the term "lang" in this [documentation page](https://designers.hubspot.com/docs/hubl/hubl-supported-variables)